# Problem with Cython, module import, and Pickling

Tags: python, pickle, cython

I use a custom random number generator build with Cython. I don't understand why, but it no longer works... I guess it is related to Python 2.7, or maybe a new version of Cython.

In dcmtrand.pyx, I have:

```
...
import dcmt
...
cdef class RandomState:
    ...
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (dcmt.__RandomState_ctor, (), self.get_state())
    ...
```

dcmt is a folder. In it, I have **init**.py file:

```
from dcmtrand import *

def __RandomState_ctor():
    return RandomState.__new__(RandomState)
```

I compile it using

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

then I copy resulting dcmtrand.so file into dcmt folder, and I move dcmt folder into my project.

Now, if I import dcmt, everything is ok:

```
import dcmt
import cPickle
dc = dcmt.DynamicCreator(5)
a = dc[0]
cPickle.dumps(a)
```

But if I want to put dcmt into a subpackage, it no longer works:

```
from prng import dcmt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "prng/dcmt/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from dcmtrand import *
  File "dcmtrand.pyx", line 10, in init dcmtrand (dcmtrand.c:6955)
ImportError: No module named dcmt
```

To make it work, I need to add prng to Python path.

Why it is no longer working? How to make it work again?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have 3 choices:

1. Set PYTHONPATH to have dmct in it: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:prng`
2. Use sys.path:

   ```
   from os.path import dirname, join
   import sys
   sys.path.append(join(dirname(__file__), 'prng')
   ```
3. Do the same inclusion as in your .py: `from prng import dcmt`

Comment: But why was it working before? Did something changed in the way Python interpret relative paths?

Comment: 100% your machine environment changed, and some global variables got updated / overwritten